# If $f(2x)=2f(x)$ and $f(10)=40$. Find $f(1/4)$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(2x)=2f(x)$ for every real number $x$. If $f(10)=40$, calculate $f(1/4)$.

It is clear that $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}f(2x)$. From this I can get many values of $f(x)$, but I am not managing to find a relationship between $f(10)=40$ and $f(1/4)$.

Any idea how I can solve that problem?

Comment: There is no constraint on $f(1/4)$ based only on $f(10)$. This is because of unique factorization: $10$ is divisible by $5$, the relationship on $x$ and $2x$ passes through powers of $2$, and $1/4$ has no $5$ factor. Stated differently, the $5$-adic valuations of $40$ and $1/4$ are different, and thus $f$ doesn't relate them at all.

Comment: Aren’t you forgetting an assumption on $f$… continuity would help!

Comment: This looks like Schröder's equation to me.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two functions $f_i : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ satisfying $f_i(2x) = 2f_i(x)$ and $f_i(10) = 40$.

1. Define $f_1(x) = 4x$.
2. (a) Define $f_2(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational or $x = 0$. Otherwise, (b), $x$ is a non-zero rational and has a unique representation of the form $x = \pm p_1^{i_1}p_2^{i_2}\ldots$ where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime, $i_n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and all but finitely many $i_n$ are $0$. In case (b) we define $f_2(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(x) \cdot 20 \cdot 2^{i_1}$.

These examples show that your conditions don't define a unique function $f$ and don't determine $f(1/4)$ (because $f_1(1/4) = 1$ while $f_2(1/4) = 5$).

Answer (score 2):

As said by @davidlowryduda in your comments, you can't guess $f(1/4)$ with these information only, even if you assume $f$ to be continuous. Indeed, take $A$ your favorite positive real number, and take,
$$
f(x) = x\exp\left(\frac{\ln(4) - \ln(4A)}{1 - \cos(2\pi\log_2(10))}(1 - \cos(2\pi\log_2(|x|))) + \ln(4A)\right)
$$
It can seem a bit complicated like that but once you notice that for all $x \neq 0$,
$\cos(2\pi\log_2(|2x|)) = \cos(2\pi(\log_2(|x|) + 1)) = \cos(2\pi\log_2(|x|))$, you deduce easily that $f(2x) = 2f(x)$ for all $x$ (and for $x = 0$, $f(0) = 0$). Then, we can compute that $f(1/4) = A$ and $f(10) = 40$.